# Check how long it will take for tmutil restore to complete

Tags: terminal

I’m restoring my HDD from a time machine backup from the terminal (so I can use my computer while it restores).

It’s working but just seeing if there’s a way to check how long it will take to finish?

I’m not tech-savvy so if there’s an answer out there please explain in basic layman’s terms 
Cheers